# Как исключить значения из foreach на php?

Tags: php

Имеется многомерный массив, выдача значений через foreach

```
 foreach ($arr as $value) {
     echo "<td>Значение: $value</td>\n";
 }
```

Как вы уже понимаете, результат выводится в виде таблицы:

```
Пирожок Булка Ложки Перец Укроп
Пирожок Булка Вилка Перец Укроп
Пирожок Хлеб  Нож Перец Укроп
Пирожок Булка Штопор Перец Укроп
```

Возможно не покасывать массивы в foreach, в которых присутствует значение, например Хлеб?

Comment: перед новой строкой пишем `if (!in_array('Хлеб', $array)) {...` и всё ..... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

Comment: @Dvashington $value это у Вас массив или строка? Просто у вас вывод один, а код другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем предложу свой ответ, так как не очень удобно обварачивать в if полностью блок `foreach` не очень красиво так как после могут быть записаны ещё какие либо действия.

```
$unexcepted = array(
   'Хлеб'
);

foreach($arr as $_value) {
   if(in_array($_value,$unexpected)) {
       continue; // если нашли повторяем цикл
   }
   echo "<td>Значение: $_value</td>\n";
   // тут ещё какая то логика представления 
}
```

так же можно использовать `array_map` перед foreach для очистки массива от ненужных значений

```
$arr = array_map(function($element) use $unexpected {
   if(in_array($element,$unexpected) {
      unset($element);
   }
},$arr);
```

Comment: Видимо, я что-то делаю не так, но у меня данные выводятся все равно все.

Comment: Var_dump($_value) сделай в начале цикла.

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "28"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "t"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "chown -R user ./foldername"
  [3]=>
  string(69) "Смена владельца для папки с рекурсией"
  [4]=>
  string(38) "user - имя пользователя"
} Мой код $un = array('t');  foreach($get_csv as $_value) {
echo '<tr>';
   if(in_array($_value,$un)) {
 continue; }
       echo '<pre>';
       var_dump($_value);
       echo '</pre>'; echo "<td>$_value[0]</td>\n";
   echo "<td>$_value[1]</td>\n";
   echo "<td>$_value[2]</td>\n";
   echo "<td>$_value[3]</td>\n";
   echo "<td>$_value[4]</td></tr>";
   }

Comment: @Dvashington а при чём тут "Хлеб" сравнивайте с тем что нужно

Comment: Был предоставлен простой пример, значения были другие, массивы были больше. Собственно, я убрал массив из исключения и оставил лишь string значение - все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

создайте массив в котором список значений которые не надо выводить и проверяйте функцией in_array

$arr - массив с исключениями

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $arr)){
        echo "<td>Значение: $value</td>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем прикол вашего условия?

Comment: @Visman думаю это всё таки опечатка у человека